# How to login in Skype via Facebook?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, facebook, skype

I have a skype account that I created via Facebook login and can use it on my PC or Mac just fine. Now I want to use Skype on Android and have installed the official app. Yet the app lacks an option to login via Facebook.

How am I supposed to login, as I do neither know my user name nor the password, as I am used to login via Facebook.

Comment: I know that as of last year, Facebook login [wasn't supported on Android](http://community.skype.com/t5/Android/SKype-login-with-facebook-on-android/td-p/1779723). I don't know if that has changed since then.

Answer (score 5):

1. Go to the login page, tap on "Problems in signing".
2. Enter your primary Facebook email, Skype will send a code to your email.
3. Copy it, go back to the Skype app.
4. Tap on enter the key, paste the key in it.
5. There's your Skype account named `facebook:your.name`.
6. Tap on your Facebook profile, tap sign in with Facebook
7. Then Facebook login page will appear and enter your login info.